# How to increase execution speed in php when handling large array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

If my question was stupid please forgive me. but please some one tell me or suggest me how to fix this issue. Actually i have large multidimensional array

like this

```
   $array_value =  Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => sdfsf
                        [1] => fghbfh
                        [2] => sgddfsg
                        [3] => ujmnm
                        [4] => jkluik
                        ..
                        ..
                        ..
                        ..
                        ..
                        ..
                        [150] => jhbjhbjh
                     )
                 [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 44062
                        [1] => 45503
                        [2] => 44062
                        [3] => fdg
                        [4] => dfgdg
                        ..
                        ..
                        ..
                        ..
                        ..
                        ..
                        [150] => jhbjhbjh
                     )
              ....
              ....
              ....
               [590] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 44062
                    [1] => 45503
                    [2] => 44062
                    [3] => fdg
                    [4] => dfgdg
                    ..
                    ..
                    ..
                    ..
                    ..
                    ..
                    [150] => jhbjhbjh
                 )
    )
```

600 array inside of 600 array i have 150 array values. When i use this array if foreach condition and for loop condition it takes more than 5 minutes to complete the execution.

i m using two foreach loop and one for loop and 4 method function inside the loops. it takes more than 5 minutes to execution. I need to load faster.

I dont know how to increase the execution time of script or how to handle this array. please someone suggest or help me how to handle this issue. Thank you.

```
        foreach ($Final_Data as $line_no => $val) {
            foreach($val as $col_name=> $col_value) {

                if ($col_name === 'tid' || $col_name === 'pid' || $col_name === 'local_list_id') 
                {
                        if(empty($col_value)) {
                           $null_error[] = "empty value in ".$col_name;
                        }elseif( $col_value !== null && !is_numeric( $col_value) ) {                        
                            $where_Error[] ="non numeric value in ".$col_name." = ".$col_value;
                        }
                        $where_content[]= $col_name . "= '" . $col_value."'";

                        if($col_name =='pid'){
                            $pid = $col_value;
                        }   

                }elseif(!empty($col_name) && in_array($col_name, $update))
                {

                        if($col_name=="country"){
                                ...
                        }elseif($col_name=="state"){
                                ...
                        }elseif($col_name=="district"){
                                ....
                        }elseif($col_name=="post_category")
                        {
                        ....


                            $CategoryList=array();                          
                            if(count($locationArr) > 0 && count(locationCategory($locationArr)) > 0)
                            {
                                .....
                            }




                            if(strlen($col_value)==0 || empty($col_value))
                            {
                                    ......
                             }elseif(ValidateLength($col_name,$columnValue,$maxl) === false || VulnerableExists($columnValue)===false)
                             {
                                   if(ValidateLength($col_name, $columnValue,$maxl) === false){
                                        ....
                                    }
                                    if(VulnerableExists($columnValue)===false){
                                        ....
                                    }
                             }else
                             {
                                    ......



                                    foreach($post_cat as $Category){



                                        if(get_cat_ID($Category) == 0) {                                        
                                            if(!in_array($Category, $CategoryList)){
                                            .....
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }




                                    /*****Category Mapping Start****/
                                    if(count($post_cat)>0 && isset($pid) && !empty($pid) && count($CategoryList)==0)
                                    {
                                        $postCat = array(); 
                                        $ex_catid = array();

                                        $post_categories = get_the_category( $pid );                                

                                        foreach($post_categories as $category) {

                                            if(in_array($category->name, $post_cat)){   
                                                .....
                                            }
                                        }



                                        $array_dif = array_diff($post_cat,$postCat);




                                        foreach($array_dif as $pc){
                                                ......
                                                if($cat_Id!=0) array_push($ex_catid,$cat_Id);
                                        }
                                        if(count($array_dif)!=0){
                                            ......
                                        }

                                     }elseif(count($CategoryList)>0)
                                     {

                                     }
                            }
                        }

                            $columnName=$col_name;
                            $columnValue=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $col_value);      



                        if(ValidateLength($col_name,$col_value,$maxl)===false)
                        {
                            ......
                        }elseif(VulnerableExists($col_value)===false)
                        {
                        ......
                        }else
                        {
                        ......
                        }           



                }                           
            }           


        die();



            //  echo implode(", " ,$where_content)."<br>";
            //  echo  implode(", " ,$update_content);

                if(!empty($val['pid']) && !empty($val['tid']) && !empty($val['local_list_id']) ) {
                    if(count($vuln_error) <= 0 && count($length_error)<=0 && count($null_error)<=0  && count($CategoryList)<=0){
                        ....

                    }else
                    {
                        ....

                    }                   
                }


                //die();
            unset($where_content);
            unset($update_content);
            unset($null_error);
            unset($vuln_error);
            unset($length_error);
            unset($CategoryList);
            echo "<br><br>";


        }
```

i have given just basic structure of my code. this is how my entire script will have many if condition inside the forloop and foreach condition. but all the condition are compulsory because it is for validation and some operation. please someone help me to fix this problem. Thankyou

most important thing and problem in this array is the value are 1000 character and more than 1000 characters. here i have just given 4 digits and 5 character string.

Comment: Do you know the total number of 'columns' in each small array ? Are the array keys always simple index numbers ?

Comment: what is the validation_funtion job? And where do you use $value

Comment: the small array create dynamically depend upon excel file.  If the file has 150 column then the key will be 150 or it will be below 150. maximum is 150 @besciualex

Comment: @hurricane my actual code is more than 500 lines i just tried to explain that i have used two foreach and inside foreach there are validation function and many if condition.

Comment: @Munna Thanks for answer. I ran a few tests and parsing an array like you described is pretty fast. What makes your script slower is actually the if {} else {} statements and validation function. I suggest you to put inside if() condition the condition that occurs the most often. Basic example: if (a==b) { /*write here the code that happens often than the one on else statement */}

Comment: thankyou bsescuiex .. the problem is some value will have more than 1000 character ( 4 essay or 4 paragraph) and some value will have more than 500 characters @besciualex

Comment: We may help you if you post the 'validation' process. Simply strip sensitive things from your code and post it here. In my opinion there is the thing you need improved.

Comment: @besciualex please check i have updated question

Comment: I suspect the 'in_array' is worth looking at. How does the index in the 150 array entry map to columns? imo, I suspect that the validation would be more useful as functions in arrays being passed the appropriate data to check rather then `nested if else statments`. I need more information as to what happens for, say,  `... } elseif ($col_name=="district") {...`.

Comment: @RyanVincent thankyou .. yes valid point. check 150 key array using in_array might take time think so... but what can i do alternate solution can i use . Inside if() and elseif() i m just pushing values in another array

Comment: How do you map any of the 150 values to a particular column. And, therefore, to the required validation for the value(s)? That is what I would structure  differently.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of if else in for loop we can use array_key_exists() and also can use ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can user array_walk function to reduce your foreach loops...

Comment: Please do not answer with a comment/question. Understandably, your rep is too low to comment, but that still does not mean answers should be used to make comments as an alternative.